# 256 and 64 bit number in assembly 6502

Tags: assembly, 6502

I have to Write a code  in 6502 assembly language that divides 256-bit numbers by 64-bit numbers using basic bit shift operations, and arithmetic and logic operations.
i just don't know how  to write 256 and 64 bit number in assembly 6502.

Comment: Can you do it in C?  Define a numeric representation for these large numbers?  Obviously, neither C nor assembly support 256-bit numbers directly, so you will have to compose something to get there.

Comment: Erik Eidt thanks for answering .
I m trying to solve  it for 2 days know still can't work it out .
everything mu be in  6502 not aloud to use C.

Comment: Here's the reason to do it in C first: you need a numeric representation, and an algorithm that works with that.  *Doing that from scratch in assembly is very hard when you don't know assembly*.  So, do the design (an algorithm and numeric representation) in C, then, knowing that it works, translate into 6502 assembly.  Design problems are very hard to debug in assembly, so get it fully working in C and then translate it literally.  (You can continue C code for a while, moving it closer to 6502 by restricting the data types and operations (and control structures) as are available on 6502.)

Comment: What are you programming? a 256-bits number en 6502 is not common.

Comment: Was sep roland able to help you with their answer?

Answer (score 3):

> i just don't know how to write 256 and 64 bit number in assembly 6502.

You would store these as strings of **32** and **8** bytes respectively.

In memory, the qword number $1122334455667788 would look like these 8 bytes:

```
$88, $77, $66, $55, $44, $33, $22, $11
```

Similar and 4 times longer for a 256-bit number.

---

To get an idea of how to work with multibyte numbers. This is the addition of a couple of 16-bit numbers.
If *NumA* is $1122 and *NumB* is $3344, then the sum will be *Res*:

```
CLD
CLC
LDA NumA    ; -> A = $22
ADC NumB    ; -> A = $22 + $44 = $66
STA Res
; The carry propagates to the higher order addition
LDA NumA+1  ; -> A = $11
ADC NumB+1  ; -> A = $11 + $33 = $44
STA Res+1
```

*Res* now holds the sum $4466.

Working with very big numbers will require a loop. Next is the addition of two qwords:

```
 CLD
 CLC
 LDY #8        ; Qwords have 8 bytes
 LDX #0
Loop:
 LDA NumA,X
 ADC NumB,X
 STA Res,X
 INX           ; INX and DEY don't clobber the carry
 DEY           ; and thus it can propagate
 BNE Loop
```